# Formula for grid that supports 2:1 and 1:1 units?

Tags: page-layout, grids

I'm trying to create a grid that supports 2:1 and 1:1 units. I cannot figure out if this can be done or is even mathematically possible without compromising the 1:1 or 2:1 unit.

- The grid will be 1024px wide.
- Using the 1:1 unit as a base for columns, ideally there are six columns.
- The height should support at least two or three rows of units.
- The gutters should be 4px, maximum of 6px, minimum of 2px.
- Ideally no margins, but there can be very small margins the same width as the gutter at most.

I'd like this to be pixel perfect, by this I mean the solution does not involve half-pixels or breaking the 1:1 or 2:1 units.

This might not be possible, unfortunately my maths isn't strong enough to be sure!

Comment: You might be better off with 960px, which allows for lots of flexible divisions.

Comment: It's not necessarily the width that is the issue. 1024px also allows for lots of flexible divisions, however the key here is finding a formula for a grid which supports 2:1 and 1:1 units, alongside the criteria for the margins and gutters.

Also, this is not necessarily a grid for the web!

Thank you anyway Lauren.